# Append Loop Variable to Variable Name

Tags: c#, string, for-loop, iterator, append

I have 5 DataTables that needs to be converted to TXT files. Instead of creating them separately, I thought I use a `for` loop. Here's my code:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
{
    DataTable dtFile1 = file1BLO.SelectFile1ForCSV()
    foreach (DataRow dr in dtFile1.Rows)
    {
        string[] fields = dr.ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString()).ToArray();
        sb.AppendLine(string.Join("|", fields) + "|");
    }
    Response.ContentType = "application/text";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=CAPRES-FILE1-"
                + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss") + ".txt");
    Response.Output.Write(sb);
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
    sb.Clear();
}
```

I would want the iterator to be appended to the variable names and methods. Like this `DataTable dtFile + i = file + i + BLO.SelectFile + i + ForCSV();`

Thanks!

Requested Code for SelectFile1ForCSV()

```
public DataTable SelectFile1ForCSV()
{
    return file1DAO.SelectFile1ForCSV();
}
```

**EDIT:** I am sorry, it seems that I haven't provided enough details, and my question has caused confusion. Edited now.

Comment: Please show (the body of) `SelectFile1ForCSV()`

Comment: If there are five files, shouldn't it be `i = 1` or `i < 5`?

Comment: @Robert Good catch! I'll edit it.

Comment: Response.End inside the loop?

Comment: @codroipo What's wrong? Should it be outside the loop?

Comment: Please show (the body of) `file1DAO.SelectFile1ForCSV()`. You'll need to add some parameter here to get a parameterized filename.

Comment: @DrKoch Can't I just append the loop iterator?

Comment: Where's `file1DAO` declared? Stop putting `1` in all your method and variable names and simply pass `i` as a parameter to the point where you build a filename.

Comment: You might append "(1)" to the **filename**. So you need access to the filename. I can't see any filename in the question you posted.

Comment: @DavidArno file1DAO is declared in file1BLO, which is declared in the code-behind. I have File1, File2, File3, File4, and File5 database tables, and I have created separate Data Access Objects and Business Logic Objects for each tables, hence why I have separate classes.

Comment: @DrKoch I'm sorry, my original question is not clear. I've edited it. I don't have files, but I have DataTables with data from a database.

Comment: So please don't call a DataTable "file". Also your question says "convert to txt files". Where does this happen? Where are the (outgoing) files defined?

Comment: @DrKoch I'm sorry, but I got the two terms mixed up, since the names of my DataTables and SQL Tables are File1, File2, etc. This will happen in the OnClick event of a button.

Comment: So PLEASE show the OnClick event code

Comment: @DrKoch The code above is already the OnClick code. The button can only export the said DataTables to Txt files, nothing else.

Comment: May I know what is "file1BLO"? Object? Where did you declare? That object also you want "file2BLO", "filie3BLO", etc ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot just append a number to a variable name at runtime to magically reference a new variable. What you should do instead is:

Define an an interface:

```
public interface IFileBLO
{
    DataTable SelectFileForCSV();
}
```

Have `File1BLO`, `File2BLO` etc all implement `IFileBLO` and fix the method names so that they are all `SelectFileForCSV` rather than `SelectFile1ForCSV` etc.

Add a lookup for reference these objects:

```
var bloList = new IFileBLO[]
{
    file1BLO, file2BLO, file3BLO, file4BLO, file5BLO
};
```

Finally, change your loop to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    var dtFile = bloList[i].SelectFileForCSV();
    foreach (var dr in dtFile.Rows)
    {
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

There are not enough information in the question to know exactly what the problem is, so I'm just guessing here. Your problem is that you have five objects, that all have a method, and these method have different names. The methods return the same thing, though, `DataTable`, that can be used in a loop.

If that's the case then just take out of the loop that which is different, so that in the loop remains that which is identical. Something like this:

```
DataTable[] fiveTables =
{
    file1BLO.SelectFile1ForCSV(),
    file2BLO.SelectFile2ForCSV(),
    file3BLO.SelectFile3ForCSV(),
    file4BLO.SelectFile4ForCSV(),
    file5BLO.SelectFile5ForCSV()
}

for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    // Use fiveTables[i] for DataTable, and i for file name
}
```

Comment: This püart **reads** the data from the database. It misses writing .txt files (as the original question)

Comment: Also: `i <=5` instead `i<5`

Comment: You are correct sir. I'll try this. Why haven't I thought of creating a DataTable array? Hehe. Thanks!

Comment: @Jeano This is the quick and dirty fix, but there is a more elegant (and proper) way. See answer from David Arno for that.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=CAPRES-FILE"
            + i
            + "-"
            + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss") + ".txt");
```

This will create a filename containing the value of `i`.

Comment: That's only part of the problem. The main problem is working with the right object in the loop. Other two answers address that.

Comment: Yes, and this answer answers the second part of the problem.